# Avocado Oil Moisturizer- Edible?

Tags: oil, avocados

I bought a bottle of avocado oil to cook with, but I failed to realize that the label was for moisturizer, not food.  The label says that it is pure, 100% avocado oil, not scented or anything.  I know the old motto "when in doubt," etc., but if it really is pure avocado oil then there shouldn't be a problem with me cooking with it, right?

Comment: Sorry, but when it comes to food safety, we cannot give you a guarantee that the FDA or the manufacturer won't give you. Any opinion that it is safe or not is just that, personal opinion, and the site cannot deal with this.

Comment: Whether or not it is labeled "food grade" isn't a matter of opinion, is it?

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan don’t post answers in comments, please.

Comment: @Erica may not be the US, no "food grade" certifications outside and wasn't an answer

Comment: @karanharshwardhan a number of countries (admittedly not all) have similar certification, regulation, or labeling; it is feasible for this to be answerable without needing to resort to opinions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No

If it is labeled "cosmetic grade" then it is *not* safe to cook with, it is only safe if it says "food grade".

I understand cosmetic grades of otherwise edible products (like cocoa butter or your avocado oil) may be made with solvents that are not food-safe, they may have trace contaminants from the processes involved, there may be any number of things that simply are present in small enough quantities to fall below the legal guidelines for labeling.

You can choose to take such a risk, if you are really sure, but it is a risk and not recommended for a reason.